# Is it possible to install a touch screen desktop environment into Ubuntu, then use it over a virtual computing app in a smartphone?

Tags: vnc

I would like to use a Digital Ocean droplet through my smartphone with a smartphone-friendly interface. I can connect to a Droplet through a VNC app. Is it possible that I could set up my Droplet with a touchable version of Ubuntu, then interact with it through a touch screen through a remote computing connection such as VNC, on my phone?

Comment: The Remote Desktop software will do all the translations between touches and clicks, so the challenge will be to find an interface that is suited to the display resolution of a phone. You may want to explore things like [Plasma Mobile](https://www.plasma-mobile.org/) 

Comment: I have the same question, but I'm wondering more about the resolution: is it possible to remote desktop from a phone to a desktop, and if the desktop has something like Ubuntu Touch installed, use a mobile friendly version of the interface instead of the desktop interface?